# How do I conduct restricted VECM in statsmodels for hypothesis testing?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, economics, vec

I am new to statsmodel and as above, would like to know how I can conduct restricted VECM in statsmodels for hypothesis testing?

Additionally, is there a way I can find the roots of a VECM model to see if it is stable in statsmodels? I have looked at the documentation, but can't seem to find the appropriate functions.